# nullPointerexception:Cannot invoke "javax.persistence.EntityTransaction.isActive()"

Tags: hibernate

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.persistence.EntityTransaction.isActive()" because "com.jspiders.hibernate.dao.StudentDAO.entityTransaction" is null
at com.jspiders.hibernate.dao.StudentDAO.closeConnection(StudentDAO.java:29)
at com.jspiders.hibernate.dao.StudentDAO.main(StudentDAO.java:52)

Cannot invoke "javax.persistence.EntityTransaction.isActive()"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Check your persistence.xml file in that gives the proper name for <persistence-unit =" ">.